# parse cloud code is not performing designated task and no log is created

Tags: docker, parse-platform, parse-javascript-sdk, parse-cloud-code

my afterSave cloud code should run after each save, but i don't see it performing the task. also no debug info is written to a local "temp.txt" file

My parse server is running on docker container (maybe it's relevant)
I did a do a clean ***docker run*** (to launch the parse server) after the main.js was created in the **/parse-server/cloud** subfolder , but still not seeing anything

how can i debug this cloud-code issue ?

my main.js content:

```
Parse.Cloud.afterSave("Post", (request) => {
var fs = require("fs");
    const image = request.object.get("image").url();
    const detail  = request.object.get("detail");
    const geo = request.object.get("geo");
    const itemId = request.object.get("objectId");
fs.writeFileSync('./temp.txt', request, function(err, data) {
  if (err) console.log(err);
});

    console.log(detail);
    console.log(image);
    console.log(geo);
    console.log('========');

var data =detail+" "+image+" "+geo+" "+request;

fs.appendFileSync("./temp.txt", data, function(err, data) {
  if (err) console.log(err);
  console.log("Successfully Written to File.");
});

    var postRequest = require('request');
    postRequest({
      method: 'POST',
      preambleCRLF: true,
      postambleCRLF: true,
      json: true,
      uri: 'https://graph.facebook.com/1111/feed?access_token=sometoken',
      body:
        {
          message: detail,
          link: image
        }
    },
    function (error, response, body) {
      if (error) {
        return console.error('upload failed:', error);
        console.log('statusCode:', response && response.statusCode);
        fs.appendFileSync("temp.txt", response+" "+ response.statusCode
                ,function(err, data) {
                       if (err) console.log(err);
                });
      }
      console.log('Upload successful!  Server responded with:', body);
    })

  }
);
```

Comment: When you instantiate the server, do you set a cloud path? Is the cloud volume attached? Have you modified the default `CLOUD_CODE_MAIN` at all?

Comment: thanks dude!
 i didn't  launch the container with the "--cloud" switch

Comment: Perfect - if you write up your solution, it should help others.

Answer (score 1):

when launching ***parse*** docker container (using "docker run" for example)  we must also pass " **The absolute path to our cloud code main.js file." (including the main.js)**

for example:

```
sudo docker run  --name parse --network=test  --appId <app-id> --masterKey <mater-key>--publicServerURL https://my-url.com/parse --databaseURI mongodb://mongo:port/mongo --cloud /parse-server/<cloudpath>/main.js
```

the missing switch inside the "**docker run**" command here was:

> --cloud /parse-server/cloudpath/main.js

this resolved the issue